# Pagination Issue: Custom Post Type In Index

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, templates, pagination

I'm using a template, which uses Custom Post Type 'movies'. When I try to change the page I got 404 Not Found :(

This is my index.php

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$page = get_query_var('page');
$page = (!empty($page) ? $page : 1);
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=movies'.'&posts_per_page=6&paged=$page');
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<div class="box " id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<div class="boxentry">
<div class="btitle">
    <h2 align="center"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Ver <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_ryear', true); ?></a></h2>
</div>
<!--div class="clear"></div-->
</div>

<div class="boxim">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="boximg" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php get_image_url(); ?>&amp;h=270&amp;w=180&amp;zc=1" alt=""/></a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img class="boximg" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/dummy.png" alt="" /></a>
<?php } ?>

</div>

</div>

<?php if(++$counter % 4 == 0) : ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php getpagenavi(); ?>
<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
</div>
```

And this is my Post Type:

```
function post_type_movies() {
register_post_type(
'movies', 
array( 'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/movie.png',
        'labels'=>array(
            'name' => _x('Movies', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Movie', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Movies'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Movie'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Movie'),
            'new_item' => __('New Movie'),
            'view_item' => __('View Movie'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Movies'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No Movies found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Movie found in Trash'), 
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
            ),                           
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position'=>5,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => TRUE,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'pelicula', 'with_front' => FALSE,),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'mytheme_add_box',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'thumbnail',
            'comments',
            'editor'
            )
        ) 
);
} 
add_action('init', 'post_type_movies');
```

Check it out at http://ddlpremium.com/peliculeros

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your [research efforts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2B%5Bcustom-post-types%5D+%2B%5Bpagination%5D+%2Bpaged&submit=search) and explain why all the other solutions didn’t work in your case. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Couple of small corrections:**

`$wp_query` is a global variable so you need to declear it as a global and i believe the query var is `paged` not `page`. so,

change

```
$temp = $wp_query;
$page = get_query_var('page');
```

to

```
global $wp_query;
$temp = $wp_query;
$page = get_query_var('paged');
```

Check if that works. Also I prefer to use Singular for CPT names. `movie` instead of `movies`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using double quotes around the query string with the variable?

Change:

```
$wp_query->query('post_type=movies'.'&posts_per_page=6&paged=$page');
```

to

```
$wp_query->query('post_type=movies'."&posts_per_page=6&paged=$page");
```

If that doesn't fix it, try dumping the query after the above code `var_dump( $wp_query )` it may show what is causing the issue.